# React Redux boilerplate error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined CachedInputFileSystem.js:145:10

Tags: reactjs, redux, boilerplate

I am trying to create a React-Redux boilerplate. But whenever I try to write some reactjs code it throws the following error:

```
E:\projects\recipeFinder\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:145
                        if(key.startsWith(what))
                              ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
    at Storage.purge (E:\projects\recipeFinder\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:145:10)
    at Storage.purge (E:\projects\recipeFinder\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:150:9)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.purge (E:\projects\recipeFinder\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:20)
    at EventEmitter.watcher.once (E:\projects\recipeFinder\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeWatchFileSystem.js:42:26)
    at EventEmitter.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at EventEmitter._onTimeout (E:\projects\recipeFinder\node_modules\watchpack\lib\watchpack.js:142:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

The package.json file looks like below:

```
{
  "name": "recipeFinder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

The webpack.config.js file looks like below:

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  watch: true,
  module:{
    loaders: [
      {
        test:/\.js$/,
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The same boiller plate used to work earlier. I think it is due to some to the latest version of the dependencies installed. Could anyone let me know ?

Thanks

Comment: Well it's kind of a bug in the package "enhanced-resolve" since it shouldn't allow empty keys (it should basically throw an error much earlier so that it can be caught in user code). Maybe try to report it on the GitHub issue page in case it's a known bug.

Comment: Also since it seems to be cache related, try to clear all the cache before installing.

Comment: It worked with the following versions of dependencies:   
   "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",

Comment: Wasted me almost 1 hour today, if you have any idea about the exact cause please tell

Comment: btw : https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/issues/97 might be related